# Can't deploy Hexo blog to Github in Cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide, hexo

I set a Hexo blog in Cloud9. I can generate it well, but nothing works when deploy to Github. It doesn't return any error information, but nothing has been pushed to Github. I don't know what to do.

[terminal info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdVzm.png)

```
...
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
INFO  Generated: css/fonts/FontAwesome.otf
INFO  28 files generated in 71 ms
younglaker@hexo-blog:~/workspace/hexo-theme-leo (gh-pages) $ hexo d
younglaker@hexo-blog:~/workspace/hexo-theme-leo (gh-pages) $
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you've configured the "_config.yml" file like this:

```
deploy: 
  type: git
  repository: https://github.com/XXXX/XXXX.github.io.git
  branch: master
```

or like this if you are using SSH key:

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: git@github.com:XXXX/XXXX.github.io.git
  branch: master
```

the repository is from the github project you build just now,and be attention to the format.